# Travis-CI error with Ruby version

Tags: ruby, rvm, travis-ci

I have the problem with Ruby version on Travis-CI.

In my Gemfile I have:

```
ruby '2.2.0'
```

In the `.travis.yml` I have:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.2.0-rc1
```

I tried also just:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.2.0
```

But always on the Travis website (in its console) I get this error:

> Your Ruby version is 2.2.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.0

What is the problem? Why Travis instal `2.2.1`? How can I specify ruby version?

I've just tried this way [enter link description here]travis documentation[1](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/ruby/)

When I change Ruby version in my `Gemfile` Travis works. But it's not what i want to.